# React-typescript: Object is of type 'unknown'. TS2571

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using React-TypeScript for my project. For state management, I am using React-redux, for function handling I am using redux-saga. For gluing the redux store and functions I am using React's new hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. I successfully pull the data and able to show it in the console.[My data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX6ZO.png). Based on useSelector documentation I can able render the `useSelector` without passing to the state. When I am mapping the `useSelector`'s variable I am getting TypeScript error: `Object is of type 'unknown'`. PS. I am new in TypeScript as well.

**This is my React functional component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ErrorBoundary from 'components/errorBoundary';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IPropertiesList } from '../../state/properties/types';
import { fetchProperties } from '../../state/properties/actions';
import { IIssueListItem } from '../../state/issues/types'
import { fetchIssuesList } from '../../state/issues/actions'
import list from '../issues/list';


export interface ITestNewListProps {
  className?: string;
}

const Test = ({ className }: ITestNewListProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const properties = useSelector<IPropertiesList | undefined>(
    (state: any) => state.properties.list.data
  );
  const issues = useSelector<IIssueListItem | undefined>(
    (state: any) => state.issues.list.data
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch the properties data from the api if we don't already have it
    !properties && dispatch(fetchProperties({}));

  }, [dispatch, properties]);

  useEffect(() => {
    !issues && dispatch(fetchIssuesList())
  }, [dispatch, issues]);

  console.log(`properties`, properties); //I can able to see the data
  console.log(`issues`, issues);


  return (
    <ErrorBoundary id="TestNewListErrorBoundary">
      <div className={`${className}`}>
        {
          properties.map(list => { // IN HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
            return <div>{list.name}</div>
          })
        }
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

Test.displayName = `Test`;

export default styled(Test)`
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the right types for your `useSelector` hook. Typically, it will be sufficient if you provide the types for your root state in the callback function.

I am not sure how are you naming the interfaces for your root state, but assuming it is called `RootState`,

```
const issues = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.issues.list.data
);
```

For this case, there is not need to provide the generic type parameters, as TypeScript should be able to infer the types of `state.issues.list.data` based on the `RootState` interface/type alias, but if you do want to provide the generic types,

```
const issues = useSelector<RootState, IPropertiesList | undefined>(
  (state: RootState) => state.issues.list.data
);
```

Do take note that the `useSelector` hook's generic type requires you to input the default root state type, as well as the selected state type.

Comment: Thank you. How will I define `RootState`?

Comment: I used `RootStateOrAny`. Like this: ` const properties = useSelector<RootStateOrAny, IPropertiesList | undefined>(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => {
      return state.properties.list.data;
    }
  );`

But I am getting still same error.

Comment: I found this typescript cheat sheet where it mentioned: `RootStateOrAny`. https://www.saltycrane.com/cheat-sheets/typescript/react/latest/#react

Comment: Nope, try not to use any for this case..! The root state is your typings for your redux state.

Comment: As for the cheatsheet, you can look search for this: `useSelector<TState = DefaultRootState, TSelected = unknown> (function)`

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: Hmm.. its hard for me to help from here too. But basically, for my code to work, you have to do the types for your redux state

Comment: I fixed it :). Man! typeScript can be sometimes pain in the neck :)

Comment: Now I am facing another issue :D . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679036/react-typescript-property-position-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattribute